# If a sphere is rotated so that $90°$N $0°$E is transformed to $50°$N $6°$E, to which point is $18°$N $77°$E transformed?

Tags: rotations, spherical-coordinates, spheres

If a sphere is rotated so that point $90°$N $0°$E is moved along a great circle to point $50°$N $6°$E, to which point is point $18°$N $77°$E moved?

$90°$N $0°$E $\implies 50°$N $6°$E

$18°$N $77°$E $\implies ?$

Is there a general formula involving spherical coordinates?

Comment: Isn't there an infinite number of possible positions of the source point, based on any possible rotation around the new "polar" axis?

Comment: There's an infinite number of answers all within a circle as once you move the north pole to its new position you can spin the globe on on axis.  I'm sure there's a general solution that be figured by trig.  rotating but x degrees east west moves a, b to a+x, b.  rotating by y degrees north south along the 0 longitide moves a+x, b to ... well I'm too lazy right now

Comment: I would assume you are supposed to rotate $40^\circ$ around an axis through $0^\circ N, 96^\circ E$ and $0^\circ N, 84^\circ W$  That doesn't mean I can answer the question, but I think the intent can be guessed.

Comment: Edit: *moved along a great circle*